# LightGBM plot tree not matching feature importance

Tags: plot, decision-tree, lightgbm

I am plotting a model from lightgbm and am trying to view the plot tree. When I use plot.tree it works... however, the output of the tree does not match feature importance, nor does it match the # of leafs I have choosen in my optimzation of my parameters.

for example, Feature A is the most important feature in my feature importance plot, but this feature does not show up in my actual decision tree plot as a node to have a decision on. Also, one of my parameters is 22 leaves, but the tree plot has 24 leaves.

I am doing this within databricks environment using python.

any ideas what is happening?

I can't post code, sorry. anyone with a general idea of what is happening will help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Ligthgbm is a Boosting ensemble method, which means that you create several tree in series.

So, which tree are you plotting? You have several trees, and only exploring one tree is not representative of how exactly the model works. For sure, if you check a few trees, your feature A should appear.

About different `num_leaves`, I don't have a clear answer. It makes no sense. I should have some code and output to analyze it (but I have seen in you comment that you can't provide it, don't worry). In theory, you shouldn't have any tree with more than 22 leaves if you specified this value... Anyway, you can try to use another hyperparameter: `max_depth`, which is quite similar, event better.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I feel like a dolt for not remembering plot.tree has parameter tree_index = X. This solves my issue. Really appreciate it.